# DMVPN Tunnel Spoke sending registration requests but Hub does not get it

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp, troubleshooting, vrf-lite

I have built a topology in GNS3 with five routers with a goal to perform:

1)inter vrf routing with bgp as the routing Protocol between Routers.
2)build DMVPN tunnel on the top of it.

I was successful in the 1st task but stuck with the second one. I have one DMVPN router which is spoke, one R1 which is Hub and a WAN between them. DMVPN router seem to be generating nhrp registration requests but the hub is not receiving the nhrp registration requests. but underlay routing seems to be fine because i can ping from one Router's Public IP to another.

I am attaching the configs of all the Routers in comments and also the Topology I am working on.

I have been stuck on this thing from the past two days. Any help would be appreciated

Thank You in advance!
[image]

```
DMVPN Config

DMVPN#sh run  
Building configuration...  
Current configuration : 2393 bytes  
!  
version 15.2  
service timestamps debug datetime msec  
service timestamps log datetime msec  
!  
hostname DMVPN  
!  
boot-start-marker  
boot-end-marker  
!  
!  
!  
no aaa new-model  
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable    
ip cef  
!  
ip vrf spoke1  
 rd 65000:1  
!    
no ip domain lookup    
no ipv6 cef    
!  
!  
multilink bundle-name authenticated  
!
!  
!  
!  
ip tcp synwait-time 5  
!  

!  
!  
!  
!  
interface Loopback0  
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255  
!  
interface Tunnel0  
 ip vrf forwarding spoke1  
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0  
 no ip redirects  
 ip nhrp authentication DMVPN  
 ip nhrp map multicast 50.50.21.2  
 ip nhrp map 192.168.1.2 50.50.21.2  
 ip nhrp network-id 1  
 ip nhrp nhs 192.168.1.2  
 tunnel source FastEthernet0/0  
 tunnel mode gre multipoint  
!  
interface FastEthernet0/0  
 ip vrf forwarding spoke1  
 ip address 50.50.1.2 255.255.255.0  
 duplex full  
!  
interface FastEthernet1/0  
 no ip address  
 speed auto  
 duplex auto  
!  
interface FastEthernet1/1  
 no ip address  
 shutdown  
 speed auto  
 duplex auto  
!  
interface FastEthernet2/0  
 ip vrf forwarding spoke1  
 ip address 172.16.1.10 255.255.255.0 
 speed auto  
 duplex auto  
!  
!  
!  
router bgp 5000  
 bgp log-neighbor-changes  
 !  
 address-family ipv4 vrf spoke1  
  network 172.16.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0  
  neighbor 50.50.1.1 remote-as 5001  
  neighbor 50.50.1.1 activate  
 exit-address-family  
!  
!  
ip forward-protocol nd   
!  
!  
no ip http server  
no ip http secure-server  
!  
!  
!  
!  
control-plane  
! 
line con 0  
 exec-timeout 0 0  
 privilege level 15  
 logging synchronous  
 stopbits 1  
line aux 0  
 exec-timeout 0 0  
 privilege level 15  
 logging synchronous  
 stopbits 1  
line vty 0 4  
 login  
!  
!  
end
```

R1 config:

```
R1#sh run  
Building configuration...  

Current configuration : 2234 bytes 
!  
version 15.2  
service timestamps debug datetime msec  
service timestamps log datetime msec  
!  
hostname R1  
! 
boot-start-marker  
boot-end-marker  
!  
!  
! 
no aaa new-model 
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable  
ip cef 
! 
ip vrf hub 
 rd 65000:2 
!
!  
!  
!  
!  
!  
no ip domain lookup  
no ipv6 cef  
!  
!  
multilink bundle-name authenticated  
!
!  
!  
ip tcp synwait-time 5  
!
!
!
!
!  
!  
!  
!  
!  
!  
!  
!  
interface Loopback1  
 ip address 5.5.5.5 255.255.255.255  
!  
interface Tunnel0  
 ip vrf forwarding hub  
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0  
 no ip redirects  
 ip nhrp authentication DMVPN  
 ip nhrp map multicast dynamic  
 ip nhrp network-id 1  
 tunnel source FastEthernet1/0  
 tunnel mode gre multipoint  
!  
interface FastEthernet1/0  
 ip vrf forwarding hub  
 ip address 50.50.21.2 255.255.255.0  
 speed auto  
 duplex auto  
!  
interface FastEthernet1/1  
 ip vrf forwarding hub  
 ip address 172.16.21.10 255.255.255.0  
 speed auto  
 duplex auto  
!  
!  
!  
router bgp 5002  
 bgp log-neighbor-changes  
 ! 
 address-family ipv4 vrf hub  
  bgp router-id 3.3.3.3  
  network 172.16.21.0 mask 255.255.255.0  
  neighbor 50.50.21.1 remote-as 5001  
  neighbor 50.50.21.1 activate  
 exit-address-family  
!  
!  
ip forward-protocol nd  
!  
!  
no ip http server  
no ip http secure-server  
!  
!  
!  
!  
control-plane  
! 
line con 0  
 exec-timeout 0 0  
 privilege level 15  
 logging synchronous  
 stopbits 1  
line aux 0  
 exec-timeout 0 0  
 privilege level 15  
 logging synchronous  
 stopbits 1  
line vty 0 4  
 login  
!  
!  
end 




WAN#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2431 bytes
!
version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
!
hostname WAN
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
ip vrf hub
 rd 65000:2
 route-target export 65000:2
 route-target import 65000:1
!
ip vrf spoke1
 rd 65000:1
 route-target export 65000:1
 route-target import 65000:2
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
no ipv6 cef
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255
!
interface Loopback1
 ip vrf forwarding spoke1
 ip address 4.4.4.4 255.255.255.255
 shutdown
!
interface Loopback2
 ip vrf forwarding hub
 ip address 5.5.5.5 255.255.255.255
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip vrf forwarding spoke1
 ip address 50.50.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex full
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip vrf forwarding hub
 ip address 50.50.21.1 255.255.255.0
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface FastEthernet4/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet4/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet6/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
router bgp 5001
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 !
 address-family ipv4 vrf hub
  redistribute connected
  neighbor 50.50.21.2 remote-as 5002
  neighbor 50.50.21.2 activate
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv4 vrf spoke1
  redistribute connected
  neighbor 50.50.1.2 remote-as 5000
  neighbor 50.50.1.2 activate
 exit-address-family
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

WAN Config

```
WAN#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2431 bytes
!
version 15.2
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
!
hostname WAN
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
ip vrf hub
 rd 65000:2
 route-target export 65000:2
 route-target import 65000:1
!
ip vrf spoke1
 rd 65000:1
 route-target export 65000:1
 route-target import 65000:2
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
no ipv6 cef
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255
!
interface Loopback1
 ip vrf forwarding spoke1
 ip address 4.4.4.4 255.255.255.255
 shutdown
!
interface Loopback2
 ip vrf forwarding hub
 ip address 5.5.5.5 255.255.255.255
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip vrf forwarding spoke1
 ip address 50.50.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex full
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip vrf forwarding hub
 ip address 50.50.21.1 255.255.255.0
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet2/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface Serial3/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface Serial3/3
 no ip address
 shutdown
 serial restart-delay 0
!
interface FastEthernet4/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface FastEthernet4/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 speed auto
 duplex auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet6/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 negotiation auto
!
router bgp 5001
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 !
 address-family ipv4 vrf hub
  redistribute connected
  neighbor 50.50.21.2 remote-as 5002
  neighbor 50.50.21.2 activate
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv4 vrf spoke1
  redistribute connected
  neighbor 50.50.1.2 remote-as 5000
  neighbor 50.50.1.2 activate
 exit-address-family
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Comment: Please *post* your configuration as preformatted text using `{ }`.

Comment: @TeunVink I formatted and updated the configs. They should be easy to go through now :)

Comment: can you ping the public IP?

Comment: Yes I can ping the public IPs on both the ends. @RonRoyston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running DMVPN on a VRF enabled device. Both your public interface (used as tunnel source) and your tunnel endpoint is VRF enabled.

To have the tunnel endpoint in a VRF, you need to enable VRF forwarding on the tunnel interface, which you have done.

To have the tunnel source in a VRF (called frontdoor VRF), you need two things:

1. The tunnel source interface needs to have VRF forwarding enabled
2. You need `tunnel vrf spoke1` under the tunnel, to instruct the tunnel to use the specified VRF

On R1 and DMVPN, add the following configuration:

`int tun 0
   tunnel vrf spoke1`

You can get additional information on frontdoor VRFs for example on [this blog post](http://www.networkingwithfish.com/tunnels-and-the-use-of-front-door-vrfs/).